# When I execute the compose.yml file, I get ERROR: Client version 3.8 is too new. The maximum supported API version is 1.41

Tags: docker, docker-compose

The problem I'm having executing the compose command reports an error.
ERROR: client version 3.8 is too new. maximum supported API version is 1.41
I am now confused about the version directive under the compose.yml file. What exactly does the version of this directive mean and what is the relationship between it and docker version

Does anyone know how to solve this problem, thanks a lot!

Info 1:
Here's my docker version info

```html
D:\Docker\www\laravel-madmin\localHost\docker>docker-compose up --build -d
ERROR: client version 3.8 is too new. Maximum supported API version is 1.41
D:\Docker\www\laravel-madmin\localHost\docker>docker ps
CONTAINER ID   IMAGE     COMMAND   CREATED   STATUS    PORTS     NAMES

D:\Docker\www\laravel-madmin\localHost\docker>docker version
Client:
 Cloud integration: v1.0.24
 Version:           20.10.14
 API version:       1.41
 Go version:        go1.16.15
 Git commit:        a224086
 Built:             Thu Mar 24 01:53:11 2022
 OS/Arch:           windows/amd64
 Context:           default
 Experimental:      true

Server: Docker Desktop 4.8.2 (79419)
 Engine:
  Version:          20.10.14
  API version:      1.41 (minimum version 1.12)
  Go version:       go1.16.15
  Git commit:       87a90dc
  Built:            Thu Mar 24 01:46:14 2022
  OS/Arch:          linux/amd64
  Experimental:     false
 containerd:
  Version:          1.5.11
  GitCommit:        3df54a852345ae127d1fa3092b95168e4a88e2f8
 runc:
  Version:          1.0.3
  GitCommit:        v1.0.3-0-gf46b6ba
 docker-init:
  Version:          0.19.0
  GitCommit:        de40ad0
```

Info 2:
Here's my docker-compose.yml info

```html
version: "3.8"
services:
  php-fpm-8.1.6:
    build:
      context: ../../  
      dockerfile: /localHost/docker/php8.1.6/Dockerfile
    hostname: ${COMPOSE_PROJECT_NAME}-${HOST_NAME}-php-fpm-8.1.6
    container_name: ${COMPOSE_PROJECT_NAME}-${CONTAINER_NAME}-php-fpm-8.1.6
    networks:
      - backend
    environment:
      - TZ=${TIME_ZONE}
```

Info 3:
Here's my dockerfile.yml info

```html
FROM php:8.1.6-fpm
WORKDIR /www
COPY . /www
RUN   docker-php-source extract \
    && pecl install xdebug-3.1.4 \
    && docker-php-ext-enable xdebug \
    && docker-php-source delete \
```

Info 4:compose version

```html
docker compose version    
Docker Compose version v2.5.1
```

Here are the compose versions supported by the docker engine that I copied from the official [docker website](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/compose-versioning/#compatibility-matrix)

```html
Compatibility matrix

There are several versions of the Compose file format – 1, 2, 2.x, and 3.x

This table shows which Compose file versions support specific Docker releases.
Compose file format     Docker Engine release
Compose specification   19.03.0+
3.8     19.03.0+
3.7     18.06.0+
3.6     18.02.0+
```

question 1:
Some say the problem is caused by a mismatch in the interface。

But as you can see from the picture above, my docker version is 20.10.14 and the supported compose version is greater than 3.8, so why does setting version=3.8 in the composeoe.yml file prompt an error?

question 2:
In Info 1, you can see a version information: API version: 1.41, this version is exactly the maximum version number in the error message。

```html
ERROR: client version 3.8 is too new. Maximum supported API version is 1.41
```

My confusion is what is the relationship between the version number 1.41 here and the version number in compse.yml, should I set version=1.41 or version=3.8 it, even if I set version=1.41, it will also prompt the following error

```html
ERROR: Version in ".\docker-compose.yml" is invalid. You might be seeing this error because you're using the wrong Compose file version. Either specify a supported version (e.g "2.2" or "3.3") and place your service definitions under the `services` key, or omit the `version` key and place your service definitions at the root of the file to use version 1.
For more on the Compose file format versions, see https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/
```

Can anyone help me, thanks in advance

Comment: What does `docker-compose --version` say the version is?

Comment: The docker compose version is  v2.5.1

Comment: In the `docker-compose.yml` file, does the `php-fpm-8.1.6:` service definition need to be under a `services:` block?

Comment: php-fpm-8.1.6 is placed under the services module, I changed the format in "Info 2", the previous format was pasted incorrectly

Comment: As a side note, I'm using the docker desktop version on Win11@DavidMaze

Answer (score 0):

I have found the cause of this problem，It's my own cause。

because I have another .env file, I thought the version parameter of compose.yml and COMPOSE_API_VERSION are the same. So I defined COMPOSE_API_VERSION=3.8 in the .env file, but the actual COMPOSE_API_VERSION max version number is 1.41. So the versions parameter of compose.yml should not be the same thing with COMPOSE_API_VERSION. After canceling COMPOSE_API_VERSION=3.8, the command can be executed normally

```html
#<------docker-compose.yml配置文件---------->#
####################docker系统变量 #####################
#项目名称
COMPOSE_PROJECT_NAME=my-project
COMPOSE_API_VERSION=3.8
#compose版本
#时区
TIME_ZONE=Asia/Shanghai
####################用户自定义变量 #####################
#容器名称
CONTAINER_NAME=container
HOST_NAME=host
NETWORKS_NAME=networks
VOLUME=volume
```

Thank you for your answers